# Getting Store Currencies Using Element API and Craft 3

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

How can I return the available store currencies using the Element API? I think it uses  `craft\commerce\Plugin::getInstance()->getCurrencies();`but unsure how to go about creating an endpoint for this?

Comment: Currencies (and stores) aren't an "element" in Craft (like an Entry, Product, etc.).  Is the endpoint going to the in the context of an actual element?

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I was looking to pull in the available currencies to make a currency dropdown, and allow the user to switch currencies (POSTing the new currency to the backend)